# Beacon scheduling in google beacon dashboard

Tags: scheduling, beacon, url-shortener, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

I'm working with 1 beacon advertising in Eddystone-URL and Eddystone-UID at the same time.

No problem with Eddystone-URL.

With UID, I set up several lines in the google beacon dashboard. With targeting options on all of them.

1 for Monday that opens instagram app, 1 for Tuesday-Sunday 3PM-5PM with a URL. Instagram app for Tuesday-Sunday 12AM-11AM, another URL for some other times of the day and week, etc. Not going into the whole details, it's quite complex.

As an example here is a copy of the raw `JSON` for one of the lines:

```
{
 "title": "Get a FREE Pop at XXXXXX!",
 "url": "https://mybitlylink",
 "targeting": [
{
  "startTimeOfDay": "15:00",
  "endTimeOfDay": "16:59",
  "anyOfDaysOfWeek": [
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

All my 4 URLs are bitly links so I can track the number of clicks I get on each. I haven't found a way to track the number of Instagram app opens.

I set up all my lines to not be redundant, meaning each line is for 1 unique part of the day and week. I have 15 lines total covering almost every minute of the whole week.

My problem is this: a few minutes after I saved my config, some clicks were registered on all my bitly links, whereas only one was supposed to show. Now - 2-3 hours later, all links still collect clicks, making me think all messages are triggered despite the targeting. What is curious is that each of them is collecting the same amount of clicks. I don't know if the instagram app was also shown because the beacon is installed at a customer site remote from me.

Do you think it could be a bitly click count error or that really 4 messages (+ potentially the Instagram open in app message) are broadcasted by Eddystone-UID?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting clicks from "Mountainview California" It's Google crawler.

The way these notifications work is before displaying them on your phone, the device connects to a Google resolver to find URL, website name and description and an icon. This resolver crawls your website and caches the details (including the icon image).

This is registered as a hit/click on bitly, and that is what you see :)

And unfortunately it is not possible to get stats for app intents.

Comment: I see USA as the origin for all the clicks, and I guess as I'm based in Canada, this is what it is. Is there any way to record clicks only when people view the site itself? Maybe another URL shortener? (I tried goo.gl but it does not record any click at all when it comes from the beacon).

Comment: Yes definitely. But you will have to make your own URL shortener, and recognize the Google crawler either by their user-agent and meta or using their [crawler IP's](http://ipinfodb.com/robots-ip-address-ranges.php)

This way, you can filter out all the bots and only have real human stats

Comment: Make my own shortener? Sounds like out of my reach... I made some tests with clickmeter and ALL clicks are registered as bots even after I clicked myself on the link contained on the beacon... Are we saying there is no way to record the actual human click without considerable development?

Comment: There might be other shortener doing that, but none that I am aware of. I am myself working on a project for beacon management app, and I have already implemented this feature. Had to build my own shorten embedded into the app cause I couldn't find anything that would work.
The platform I made works on Eddystone as well as Physical web, can do non ssl and time targeted for both, and 10+ app intents :)